# How to better output class diagrams using reverse engineering

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, uml, use-case

If you have built a swing Java application which consists of many event handling methods, and 'Swing' components, How do you eliminate those to better output 'sequence diagram' and/or 'class diagram'. Is there a technique generally? 
Perhaps in eclipse or netbeans IDE?

Is the only option is to manually delete the GUI and keep the normal logical methods and hope for the best. I want to be able to generate UML but to hide swing components otherwise classes are a long because of the inclusion of declared swing components.

Comment: I guess it depends on the tool that you use for UML

Comment: I'm really not sure, I am using the netbeans plugin for UML which supports reverse engineering